# How to delete rows from one table that previously belonged to another table?

Tags: sqlite

Table1 has :

- Column1a,
- Column2a, and
- Column3a

Table2 has :

- Column1b,
- Column2b, and
- Column3b

I'm looking to *undo* following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Column1a, Column2a, Column3a) 
SELECT Column1b, Column2b, Column3b FROM Table2
```

It inserts data Column1b,Column2b,Column3b from Table2 to Table1 into columns Column1a,Column2a,Column3a. I want to be able to delete those newly-inserted records from Table1. What I tried :

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Table2)
```

This statement is supposed to delete all rows from Table1 that also existed in Table2. Instead, this deleted all rows from Table1. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You need a correlated subquery! (As it is now, each Table1 row is deleted as long as table2 has at least a row, no matter which one.)

Answer (score 0):

Your delete query is effectively working like this.

Select all data in table2. Product join it to every row in table1. If any records match the record in table1 (and they do because table1 is effectively joined to every row in table1) then delete the row (I.e. every single one of them) from table1.

You need a delete with a join.

```sql
Delete from table1
Where table1.col1a = table2.col1a AND
   Table1.col2a= table2.col2b AND
   -- so on for each and every column required to match the target rows in table1. Or if you are unsure, all of them
```

Unfortunately, SqlLite does not seem to like this (older) form of a join in a DELETE statement. Therefore, in SQLLite, you will need to use one of the other methods posted here.

As per the example below, it does seem to work in a SELECT.  The following was tested at https://sqliteonline.com/

```sql
create table if not exists tbl1 (
  colA integer
);

create table if not exists tbl2 (
  colA integer
);

delete from tbl1
where tbl1.colA = tbl2.colA
;
-- Results in the error "no such column tbl2.colA" !?!?!?
-- Despite the fact that the syntax diagram appears to allow this https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

-- whereas the following runs just fine and performs an inner joins (you can insert your own data to verify)

select *
from tbl1, tbl2
where tbl1.colA = tbl2.colA
;
```

Comment: In the where clause...  i.e. `where tbl1.colA = tbl2.colA` inner joins tbl1 to tbl2 based upon colA

Comment: A WHERE clause is **not** a join.

Comment: @forpas It seems like SqlLite does not like this older form of a join *in a delete* statement (many other databases do). However, *it does seem to work in a select*. I'll update my answer with the example I have used that shows the join in a select (although

Comment: SQLite does not support joins in the DELETE statement anyway, but your code does not do any kind of joining because it does not refer to the 2nd table. It only references its columns and this is not  a join.

Comment: @forpas I am not sure what you mean by my code not referring to the 2nd table... what is the tbl2.colA reference in the where clauses? The tbl2 is a reference to another table called tbl2. Thus `where tbl1.colA = tbl2.colA` is a join from tbl1 to tbl2. Anyway, it is clear SQLite does not support this syntax for a delete, so the point is moot. I've updated my answer to show that this appears to work for a select.

Comment: I mean that an old style join is like `FROM t1, t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col2`, but your code misses that `, t2` reference. Without it there is no join. There is only an unknown column `t2.col2`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.
The DBMS's that support the old join syntax in a delete have a special way of specifying T2 or you can simply reference it in the where clause as I have done. The reason is that you only want to delete from one table. If you said `delete from T1,T2` then it could be confusing as to what was meant. For example, on Teradata and a number of other DBMSs, if memory serves, the syntax is `delete T1 from T2 where T1.colA = T2.colA` but you can also use the syntax I have shown (or the correlated sub-query method as others have posted).

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Table2)` says to delete a row if `exists(SELECT * FROM Table2)` is true. If there are any rows in table2 it will be true and all rows will be deleted.

Instead, you need to say which columns in table1 should equal which columns table2. These should be all of the columns you used in your insert/select in a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

```
delete from table1
where exists(
  select 1 from table2
  where table1.column1a = table2.column1b
    and table1.column2a = table2.column2b
    and table1.column3a = table2.column3b
)
```

This will not reverse your insert/select with 100% accuracy. table1 and table2 may have changed. There may be rows in table1 which match rows in table2 but were not added by your insert/select.

If you have a timestamp column which is set to the time of the row's creation, you can also use that to avoid deleting rows which just happen to match the pattern.

```
delete from table1
where exists(
  select 1 from table2
  where table1.column1a = table2.column1b
    and table1.column2a = table2.column2b
    and table1.column3a = table2.column3b
) and
created_at >= [time when you did the insert]
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7f234dcf245baaebb80dce2233521166).

You also might be able to identify the range of [rowids](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) which were affected and use that. For example, if you determine that rowids 50 through 100 were added by your insert/select...

```
delete from table1
where rowid between 50 and 100
```

Of course, do this in a transaction so you can rollback if there is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQLite version is 3.15.0+ you can use [`ROW VALUES`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) in the `DELETE` statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
WHERE (Column1a, Column2a, Column3a) IN (
  SELECT Column1b, Column2b, Column3b
  FROM Table2
)
```